# List/Grid Toggle for Photo Gallery with Shadowbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listview, photo-gallery

so I'm new to this site, and new to jquery, and javascript as a whole really, but I have very good comprehension of HTML and CSS. For a class in school, I'm making a photo gallery webpage using the Shadowbox plugin. I have that part all down, but one of the requirements is to add some sort of user option that the user can change that will get saved in a cookie. (I haven't gotten to the cookie part yet) For my option, I decided to add a toggle that will switch the view of the page from a grid view (default) with images, to a list view of just the captions of the images. I figured out how to do that, but decided it could probably done in a much simpler fashion with the use of loops.

Here is the HTML I have:

```
  <body>
        <div id="preferences">
        <h1>My Photo Gallery</h1>
        <ul id="options">
            <li><a href="#" id="list"><img src="media/listview.png" alt="List view"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="grid"><img src="media/gridview.png" alt="List view"/></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="gallery">
            <a rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" class="l1 img" href="media/img1.jpg" title="Black and White Leopard Pattern"><img src="media/thumb1.jpg" alt="Black and White Leopard Pattern"/></a>
            <a rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" class="l2 img" href="media/img2.jpg" title="Snow Leopard Pattern"><img src="media/thumb2.jpg" alt="Snow Leopard Pattern"/></a>
            <a rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" class="l3 img" href="media/img3.jpg" title="Colorful Triangle Pattern"><img src="media/thumb3.jpg" alt="Colurful Triangle Pattern"/></a>
            <a rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" class="l4 img" href="media/img4.jpg" title="Tie Dye Zebra Stripe Pattern"><img src="media/thumb4.jpg" alt="Tie Dye Zebra Stripe Pattern"/></a>
            <a rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" class="l5 img" href="media/img5.jpg" title="Blue Knitted Pattern"><img src="media/thumb5.jpg" alt="Blue Knitted Pattern"/></a>
            <a rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" class="l6 img" href="media/img6.jpg" title="Black and White Damask Pattern"><img src="media/thumb6.jpg" alt="Black and White Damask Pattern"/></a>
            <a rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" class="l7 img" href="media/img7.jpg" title="Wooden Panel Pattern"><img src="media/thumb7.jpg" alt="Wooden Panel Pattern"/></a>
            <a rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" class="l8 img" href="media/img8.jpg" title="Brick Pattern"><img src="media/thumb8.jpg" alt="Brick Pattern"/></a>
            <a rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" class="l9 img" href="media/img9.jpg" title="Watercolor Pattern"><img src="media/thumb9.jpg" alt="Watercolor Pattern"/></a>
            <a rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" class="l10 img" href="media/img10.jpg" title="Orange Stripe Pattern"><img src="media/thumb10.jpg" alt="Orange Stripe Pattern"/></a>
            <a rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" class="l11 img" href="media/img11.jpg" title="Blue Scales Pattern"><img src="media/thumb11.jpg" alt="Blue Scales Pattern"/></a>
            <a rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" class="l12 img" href="media/img12.jpg" title="Woven Pattern"><img src="media/thumb12.jpg" alt="Woven Pattern"/></a>
        </div>
    </body>
```

So here is the sample that works (for the list portion anyways), but seems excessive in terms of code since I'd have to repeat for each image:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#list" ).click(function() {
        $( "a.l1" ).removeClass( "img" );
        $( "a.l1" ).addClass( "lst" );
        $( "a.l1" ).text( $( "a.l1" ).attr( "title" );
      //repeat for l1 through l12 (that`s the letter L not a 1)
    });
    $( "#grid" ).click(function() {
        $( "a.l1" ).removeClass( "lst" );
        $( "a.l1" ).addClass( "grid" );
        //actually have no idea at all how to get this back to the original img tag other than maybe .innerHTML???
      //repeat for l1 through l12 (again, that`s the letter L not a 1)
    });
}):
```

And here is kinda how I'd like it (Y'know, except in a way that works)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;
    var selcur = $( "'a.l" + i + "'" );
    var title = selcur.attr( "title" );
    var image = '<img src="media/thumb' + i + '.jpg" alt="' + title + '"/>';

    $( "#list" ).click(function() {
        while (1<=12) {
            selcur.addClass("lst");
            selcur.removeClass("img");
            selcur.text( title );
            i++;
        }
        i = 1;
    });

    $( "#grid" ).click(function() {
        while (1<=12) {
            selcur.removeClass("lst");
            selcur.addClass("img");
            selcur.text( image );
            i++;
        }
        i = 1;
    });
});
```

Please tell me how I am going about this wrong, keep in mind again I'm new to this, I appreciate any and all responses! Is there a better way to do this? I really want to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplified your code a bit using chaining (one of the reasons JQuery is so handy), and a loop for modifying the attributes.  I haven't tested it but it should do what you're after - you may have to clear the text inside your link before you append the image when you click back on grid.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#list").click(function(){
        $("#gallery a").removeClass("img").addClass("lst").each(function(index,el){
            $(el).text($(el).attr("title"));
        });
    });
    $("#grid").click(function(){
        $("#gallery a").removeClass("lst").addClass("grid").each(function(index,el){
            $(el).html("<img src=\""+$(el).attr("href").replace("img","thumb")+"\" alt\""+$(el).attr("title")+"\"/>");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried this and it didn't work for me, gave a syntax error to the console of unexpected identifier.

Comment: Sorry fixed the syntax errors and tested - should work now.  That'll teach me to do a rushed job, apologies

Comment: Thank you so much! One more minor issue that after enough hours I could probably figure out, but the image i want to revert back to would be a thumbnail (named thumb1, thumb2 etc following the pattern) Instead right now it's loading in the larger image and shrinking with the CSS, which my instructor said to not do.

Comment: Assuming your thumbs are numbered the same and in the same folder, which they seem to be, I've done a simple replace.  If not, just save it to a variable on the line above, change as necessary, and use that to set the src.

Comment: Ahh it's perfect!! Thank you so much :')